# how to display image from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, angular

I use angular2 in localhost:4200 server and I have another restfull server localhost:3000. So upload image I store in the localhost:3000 server public folder. Now I would like show this image in front ent part.
In the localhost:3000 I have this :

```
app.post("/file", function(req, res) {
    var img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../public') + '/file-1485464104882.png', 'utf8');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');
});
```

So and the front end part I have this one:

```
this.indexService.getFileById().then(result1 => {
        var res = result1 this updates src attribute of image
```

What I do wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Does indexService.getFileById() return the raw image data or a URL to the image?

Comment: this.indexService.getFileById() is a call to app.post("/file" ...
It returns raw data